# Export Users Server 2008 R2

Tags: users, export

I'm using Server 2008 R2 on a single server, AD not installed.  When I go into Server Manager and right click the "Users" folder under Local Users and Groups, I'm given the option to "Export List", which creates a nice text file of my users.  I've used the command line net user, but that only shows the username.  Is the export option available from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_useraccount | Select-Object Caption, FullName, Name, Description
```

in PowerShell and see if that gives you what you want.  You can then export to text:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_useraccount | Select-Object Caption, FullName, Name, Description | out-file c:\users\you\documents\accounts.txt
```

or csv:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_useraccount | Select-Object Caption, FullName, Name, Description | export-csv c:\users\you\documents\accounts.csv
```

or whatever.

Comment: the export feature exports name, full name and description, none of the net commands give this much info. I'm looking for a way to run the export feature from the command line.

Comment: Yes that worked.. now how do I send that to t a text file?  I've never used powershell.. :)

Comment: Append "| out-file c:\users\you\documents\accounts.txt" or "| export-csv c:\users\you\documents\accounts.csv" to the end of the above command.  (You can up-arrow to get your last command rather than retype that.)

Comment: Perfect!!! You're the best

Comment: Is there a similar command for exporting the groups?

Comment: `get-wmiobject win32_group` might do what you're looking for, Gilles.